# Typescript typechecking type in type

Tags: typescript, knockout.js

I am trying to typescript knockout komappings toJS/fromJS. I am almost all the way but I have a problem where I am unable to get rid of types when there are code that have converted forth and back one or more times.

Code example that shows the problem and what I have tried:

```
type ArrayifiedObject<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]:
    // T[P] extends NonArrayifiedObject<(infer E)> ? ArrayifiedObject<E> : // This causes problems
    T[P] extends string ? Array<string> :
    T[P] extends number ? Array<number> :
    T[P] extends object ? ArrayifiedObject<T[P]> :
    T[P];
}

type NonArrayifiedObject<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]:
    // T[P] extends ArrayifiedObject<(infer E)> ? NonArrayifiedObject<E> : // This causes problems
    T[P] extends Array<(infer E)> ? E :
    T[P] extends object ? NonArrayifiedObject<T[P]> :
    T[P];
}

interface IExample {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}

class Test {
    private toArrays<T>(obj: T): ArrayifiedObject<T> {
        // Some js lib that converts all properties that are not arrays to arrays
        return obj as unknown as ArrayifiedObject<T>;
    }

    private fromArrays<T>(obj: T): NonArrayifiedObject<T> {
        // Some js lib that convert all properties to non-arrays
        return obj as unknown as NonArrayifiedObject<T>;
    }

    public test() {
        let example: IExample = { a: '', b: 2, c: true };
        // toArrays has the type ArrayifiedObject<IExample>
        let toArrays = this.toArrays<IExample>(example);
        // fromArrays has the type NonArrayifiedObject<ArrayifiedObject<IExample>>
        let fromArrays = this.fromArrays(toArrays);
        // I want the fromArrays object to have the type NonArrayifiedObject<IExample>.
    }
}
```

As it says in the comment at the end I would like the fromArrays object to have the type NonArrayifiedObject. But if I uncomment the rows in ArrayifiedObject and NonArrayifiedObject those typings takes over and types everything (including properties in the array definition).

I am not sure if I have explained well enough. But the example I have given can be pasted into any typescript document and tested directly.

We are using typescript version 3.4.3.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would give examples about what types you expect to come out of various things like `ArrayifiedObject<{a: string, b: string[], c: string[][], d: Array<{e: string, f: string[], g: string[][]}>}>` and `NonArrayifiedObject<{a: string, b: string[], c: string[][], d: Array<{e: string, f: string[], g: string[][]>}>`.  That is, how recursive does it really need to be?

Comment: @jcalz The resulting types are already correct, so that the properties are either arrays or not. What I want is to, when converting forth and back, get rid of the layering of ArrayifiedObject and NonArrayifiedObject for each conversion. See the two last comments in the code as an example of what I want to happen.

Comment: Okay if you won’t answer my questions then maybe someone else can help you.  Good luck.